# For unsupervised learning, how to generate image set

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing

I've got unlabeled 500 pieces of RGB color image set(200x300pixel) for unsupervised learning(CNN, GAN, autoencoder).
I want to import my image set to tensorflow, instead of MNIST example.
Do I need to transform them in CSV file?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("./", one_hot=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is part of my code that trains a GAN. The files are read like this. That is one way to do this.

```
filenames = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    tf.train.match_filenames_once("D:/TensorFlow/resizedimages/*.png"))
```

Code for reference is this.

```
def train():
    filenames = tf.train.string_input_producer(
        tf.train.match_filenames_once("D:/TensorFlow/resizedimages/*.png"))
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    _, input = reader.read(filenames)
    input = tf.image.decode_png(input, channels=3)
    input.set_shape([299, 299, 3])

    batch = tf.train.batch([input],
                           batch_size=30)

    init = (tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('D:/TensorFlow/logs/1/train', sess.graph)
        tf.summary.image("Image", GeneratedImage)
        merge = tf.summary.merge_all()

        for it in range(100):
            _, X_batch =  sess.run([input,batch])
            summary,_ = sess.run([merge,D_optimizer], feed_dict={Z : samplefromuniformdistribution(20,100), X: X_batch, keep_prob: keep_prob_value})
            summary,_ = sess.run([merge,G_optimizer],feed_dict={ Z : samplefromuniformdistribution(20,100), X: X_batch, keep_prob: keep_prob_value})

            train_writer.add_summary(summary, it)
            train_writer.flush()

        train_writer.close()
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```